# How to decide domain of CanonicalUrl

Tags: canonical-url, facebook, blogger, facebook-application

I assume that I have two domains http://www.domain1.com and http://www.domain2.com with the same contents. By default, accessing DOMAIN 1 will be redirected to DOMAIN 2. Now I want to add the Facebook comment plugin into my webpage. The code is as follows

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-numposts='10' data-order-by='time' data-width='100%' expr:data-href='data:blog.canonicalUrl'/>
```

Whenever a user comments on a post, for example http://www.domain2.com/post123/, the comment will be preserved on Facebook for this link. But I want that it is preserved for the DOMAIN 1, so that when I change the domain from DOMAIN 2 to DOMAIN 3 then the Facebook comments are always preserved for the DOMAIN 1. I think the problem is: how to convert **data:blog.canonicalUrl** of DOMAIN 2 to the one of DOMAIN 1?. Anyone can help me?